# Query_first in PHP

Tags: php, coldfusion

Working with PHP, I encountered Query_first [never used before]

Further Documentation reveled that it creates and array and returns the total number of rows, is that correct, was wondering if that kinda functionality is available in my personal preferred language Coldfusion

Does queryRowToArray [cflib.org] do the same functionality

Comment: If all you want is the number of rows returned by a query, you can use `query.recordCount` in CF.

Comment: what do you mean by 'is that correct'?

Comment: @duncan -  Its not about recordcount, Here is the snippet i share, i want to understand query_first rather than getting answer, is something same is in cf or can we use some custom function in cflib.org ` $stats['users_admin'] = $db->query_first("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS val FROM ".DB_TABLE."users WHERE `type`='1';");`

Comment: i am doing it something like this <cfset stats = StructNew()>
<cfset stats.avg_days = initial.getStatistics('avg_days')>

Comment: Regarding the "is that correct", I don't think so.  This reference suggests otherwise.  http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.db-common.getrow.php

Comment: so you my assumption and the way i am writing is wrong

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question and describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i am doing nothing different, see my usage, i am using struct to store the values, so i encountered this php's query_first and started wondering how coldfusion can handle that. something that i am not aware of?. but question is getting marked negative, because i asked like what could be cf of php code

Comment: @gurpreetrandhawa - Descriptions and [code snippets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883370/query-first-in-php#comment33135396_21883370) belong in the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21883370/edit) where they are more visible, not the comments (which not everyone reads).

Comment: What connection does `initial.getStatistics('avg_days')` have to your SQL query?

Comment: If you are using a struct to store a query's values, you are doing unnecessary work.

Comment: so what's the good best practice

Comment: If you have run a query, you have a query object that you can use for a variety of things.  Using it simplifies your app, makes it run faster because you don't have copy it to anything, and requires less server RAM because it's one less variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stats['users_admin'] = $db->query_first("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS val FROM ".DB_TABLE."users WHERE type='1';");`

All you'd need to do in CF to achieve the same thing is:

```
<cfquery name="getCount" datasource="foo">
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS val FROM users WHERE type='1'
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#getCount.val#</cfoutput>

<cfset stats['users_admin'] = getCount.val>
```

Comment: got it, but my question is still there every time i need to call query so there is nothing build in right

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: `initial.getStatistics('avg_days')` calls the SELECT SUM( TO_DAYS( modified ) - TO_DAYS( created ) ) / COUNT( * ) AS val 
            FROM mytable WHERE status = 'Resolved'

Comment: getStatistics looks like a user defined function.

Comment: creating a cfc and calling from here

Answer (score 2):

Query_first looks to be a custom function in the PHP application vbulletin and not a native function in PHP. When using a query result in ColdFusion, you can use `queryObject.ColumnName` and you will reference the first record returned. For this reason, I see no need to emulate this helper function.

Using the query_First to reference your result would be:

```
$stats['users_admin']['val']
```

In ColdFusion to reference the result would be:

```
<cfoutput>#yourQueryName.val#</cfoutput>
```

Is this kind of functionality available in ColdFusion? Yes its the default behavior of the query object.

Does queryRowToArray [cflib.org] do the same functionality? NO. As defined in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) "an array in PHP is actually an ordered map". So what you would get in PHP is more or less a ColdFusion struct. The queryRowToArray will give you an array were you reference the values via an index value, not by a key value.

So if you did use the queryRowToArray, you would reference the value by:

```
<cfset yourArray = queryRowToArray(yourQueryName, 1)>
<cfoutput>#yourArray[1]#</cfoutput>
```